# Learning C++: why is this illegal?

Tags: c++, pointers

I bought the C++ Primer book few days ago, and I started learning this new language!

At the moment, I'm trying to undestand why this block I wrote myself is illegal:

I initialize a const int to 512;
I initialize a const int const pointer to n;
But it doesn't allow me to create a const int const pointer to pointer, even using correctly the double ** and everything:

```
const signed int n = 512;
const signed int *const nPointer = & n;
const signed int **const nPointer2 = & nPointer;
```

Does someone have a simple explanation? Thanks for your time!

Comment: what error did you get?

Comment: In the last line, one `const` is in the wrong place: `const signed int * const * nPointer2 = & nPointer;` It doesn't matter whether `nPointer2` is `const` (that is, can be made to point to something else) - what matters is that what it points to is `const`.

Comment: oh thanks, now I undestand!

Comment: The compiler told you why this is illegal, in its error message. It is true that C++ compilers' error messages have a reputation for being utterly confusing and incomprehensible. Still, one must learn how to read and understand C++ compiler error messages. It will take you an entire lifetime to learn C++ if you have to post a question on stackoverflow.com every time you get a compilation error. Now that you understand what the problem is, go back and reread your compiler's original message, and keep rereading it until it makes sense to you.

Answer (score 1):

In order to fix the code you have two options:

```
//Option one : 
const signed int *const nPointer = & n;
const signed int *const *const nPointer2 = & nPointer;
//Option two :
const signed int * nPointer = & n;
const signed int **const nPointer2 = & nPointer;
```

Explanation:

when nPointer is a constant pointer to T, nPointer2 should point to a constant pointer to T, as in the first option. Alternatively, when nPointer2 is a pointer to a non-const pointer to T, the pointee nPointer should be non-const as well.

when you get to the part of the book where you define your own type aliases, you can remove the clutter to see how these alternatives work as follows:

```
//simplifying notation:
using myType = const signed int *;
using myTypeC = const signed int * const;

//your code equivalent to:
myTypeC nPointer = & n;
myType *const nPointer2 = & nPointer;

//Option One:    
myTypeC nPointer = & n;
myTypeC *const nPointer2 = & nPointer;
//Option Two:    
myType nPointer = & n;
myType *const nPointer2 = & nPointer;
```

Answer (score 0):

First simplify the problem and remove the signed. The problem stays the same
Secondly, use a compiler and READ the ERROR message. This is valid for all languages, not only C++
The problem is here:

```
const int **const nPointer2 = & nPointer;
```

nPointer type is const signed int* const

Your instruction is

```
const signed int **const nPointer2 = & nPointer;
```

So you get the following message:

> error: invalid conversion from 'const int* const*' to 'const int**'

As you see, const is between your two stars. Creating a compile error.

As you see using & puts * at the **end**.